# Анимация TextView в xml

Tags: android, android-animation

В приложении во время подгрузки данных хочу отображать `textView` с анимацией такого плана, типа:
Loading. -->
Loading.. -->
Loading...--Loading.
Грубо говоря, чтобы добавлялись точки, и так по циклу, пока данные с сервера не придут, и адаптер не заполнится ими. После чего `textView` удаляю с фрагмента. 
Вопрос: можно ли как-то эту "анимацию" заложить через xml?

Comment: Ну, раз, вроде, нема такого атрибута в xml Вьюхи, то, видать, это просто невозможно. Единственное, что в голову приходит - это написать свою вьюху с таким атрибутом)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб =) Видимо придется так и делать. Думал есть решение попроще

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Может кому понадобится. Сделал так:
Создал свой объект

```
public class LoadingTextView extends LinearLayout {

    private TextView loading;
    private LinearLayout layout;

    public LoadingTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.loading_message, this);

        loading = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.loading);
        layout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.layout);


    }

    public void show() {
        layout.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        startAnimate();
    }

    public void hide() {
        layout.setVisibility(GONE);
    }

    protected void startAnimate() {
        Handler handler = new Handler();

        for (int i = 200; i <= 600; i = i + 200) {
            final int finalI = i;
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {     
                    if (layout.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                        return;
                    }  

                    if (finalI % 600 == 0) {
                        loading.setText("Loading...");
                        startAnimate();
                    } else if (finalI % 400 == 0) {
                        loading.setText("Loading.. ");
                    } else if (finalI % 200 == 0) {
                        loading.setText("Loading.  ");
                    }
                }
            }, i);
        }
    }
}
```

Вот его разметка

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/loading"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/main_dark"
        android:textSize="14sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Во фрагменте кладём таким образом

```
<com.roadlavaboy.application.core.LoadingTextView
                android:id="@+id/loadingTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Ну и управление

```
 LoadingTextView loadingTextView = (LoadingTextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.loadingTextView);
        loadingTextView.show();
```

Вроде бы всё выглядит нормально.